# Что такое Docker

Tags: docker

Что такое докер и для чего он нужен? Во всех статьях про докер встречаются термины "имейдж" и "контейнер", что эти термины означают?

**UPDATE**
В скриншоте ниже я подключился получается к какому-то контейнеру? Я сейчас нахожусь в том контейнере? Как мне из него выйти? И можно ли выйти не останавливая его и как потом обратно туда попасть?

[image: куда я попал после подключения к контейнеру]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

docker - это такая упрощенная виртуалка. Виртуалка для одной-двух программ. Виртуалка, которая стартует в доли секунды. Виртуалка, которая обещает, что если Вы предоставите специальный маленький (текстовый) докер-файл (файл конфига), то любой админ, который знает докер, сможет приготовить правильное окружение и запустить софт.

Зачем все это нужно. Вспомнить классическую ситуацию - программист написал софт и говорит "у меня на ноуте работает". А админы (сисопсы/девопсы) не могут развернуть на прод сервере и заставить работать, так как нет хорошего описания как это сделать. И на это обычно  говорят так - давай твой ноут поставим в стойку.

А вот если программист предоставил докер файл... то все сильно упрощается.

Также докер предоставляет "из коробки" всякие разные вкусности. Например, можно приложению выделить определенные ресурсы процессора/памяти, открыть порты, поставить специфическую версию какой-то библиотеки - программисты любят говорить, что их софт работает только с ограниченным набором версий библиотек.

Также можно переносить запущенные в докере приложения с машины на машину без особых проблем.

Что такое **имедж** - это подготовленный кем-то набор файлов, готовый к использованию в докере. Это может быть целый линукс, а может быть специально собранный питон, который можно "наложить" на нужный образ линукса. То есть, если админу нужно обновить ядро, он берет нужный имедж с ядном, добавляет уже готовый имедж с программами и вуаля, все работает (если только не испортили совместимость).

**контейнер** - а это уже готовый к употреблению продукт. Его можно запустить/остановить. (А вот образ не запустишь, его нужно поместить для начала в контейнер).

На самом деле, докер - это не вируталка, это инструмент управления различными средствами виртуализациями. А управляет он к примеру lxc (linux container) - почти встроенное ядро средство виртуализации).

**UPD**

**виртуалка** - как virtual box или vmware. Но теже "виртуалные сервера" можно сделать на базе докера.

изолированное окружение - это возможность сделать так, что приложение будет думать, что оно работает на сервере само. Допустим, хочется запустить десять веб серверов, а у них у всех прибит 80 порт и изменить нельзя. А докер позволит их всех запустить, каждый в своем контейнере, а наружу выпустит под разными портами. А ещё в одном докере запустить балансер, который будет с 80 порта разбрасывать запросы. А ещё к этому можно прикрутить docker-composer, который может управлять пачкой докер контейнеров.

А вот винду - да, пока не запустить в докере, но это дело наживное. Если майкрософт захочет, то сделать образ и тогда все будет буквально в пару кликов (ой, не кликов, а строк в докер файлов). Более того, поговаривают, что Майкрософт к этому готовиться - выпустили виндовс сервер без gui, интегрируют линукс внутрь... посмотрим.

Comment: в этом контексте под словом "вируталка" имеется ввиду виртуальный сервер? 
типа как локальный?

Comment: и если можно.. что значит "запустить процесс в изолированом окружении"?

Comment: Это типа еще один компьютер, но только внутри вашей операционной системы. Но Docker, как правильно отметил KoVadim, это упрощенная виртуалка - например, Windows на него не поставить

Comment: в чем тогда преймущество запуска программы в этой виртуалке? что мне мешает запускать ее локально и зачем мне это надо? зачем хранить проект на виртуалке на докере?

Comment: Это удобно! Если совсем на пальцах пример то вот: написал я приложение на PHP5, а хочу посмотреть как оно работает на PHP7. Благодаря докеру мне не нужно переустанавливать PHP на основной системе, я просто создам контейнер с PHP 7 и запущу приложение в нём.

Comment: @KoVadim я обновил вопрос, не могли бы посмотреть?

Comment: Вообще то, согласно правилам, сильно обновленный вопрос - это новый вопрос.

Comment: Но! Вы запустили докер в интерактивном режиме. Если хочется выйти с него - Ctrl+p Ctrl+q (https://docs.docker.com/engine/quickstart/#running-an-interactive-shell)

Comment: ...или изначально при запуске (`docker run`) добавить флаг `-d` и использовать `docker attach`, чтобы в него залезть.

Comment: @KoVadim а что значит докер в интерактивном режиме?

Comment: интерактивный - значит Вы имеете прямой доступ к консоли, можете работать как обычной консолью. А неинтерактивный - он работает сам по себе, выполняя поставленные на него задачи.

Comment: Насколько понимаю, докер на винде уже будет к следующему релизу. Я мельком поглядываю новости, и вроде они уже в бете с hyper-v.

Comment: @etki Docker уже есть для Windows, но только на Win10

Comment: @1d0 комментарию больше года

Comment: @etki я пришел с обновлением инфы )