# Вопрос по Docker

Tags: git, docker

Расскажите пожалуйста чем отличается докер от гитхаба?

Comment: Примерно всем. github - социальная сеть для программистов с возможностью хранить репозитории git. Docker - упрощенно говоря инструмент контейнеризации и запуска приложений в относительно независимом от остальной операционной системы окружении (как бы система внутри системы).

Comment: А расскажи пожалуйста что такого особенного в контейнерах?

Comment: Контейнер - это такой ящик. В него можно что-то положить. И он изолирует то что внутри от того что снаружи, и наоборот.

Comment: Также см.: [Что такое Docker](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/515998)

Comment: А, ну еще из одного образа контейнера можно быстро создать и запустить кучу однотипных контейнеров, которые будут что-то вместе параллельно выполнять. Или просто один - но быстро (одним действием).

Comment: чем отличается компьютер от с++? ;)

Comment: чем база данных отличается от компилятора? чем мышка отличается от витой пары? чем человек отличается от экономики? чем тёплое отличается от мягкого? ответы на все эти животрепещущие вопросы вы сможете найти теперь на нашем сайте!

Comment: Берем проект с гитхаба, билдим образ докер, размещаем в кубер.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Docker и Git - две разные технологии:

[Git](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git) - это решение для управления версиями.

[Docker](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Docker) - это запуск приложений в контейнерах.

Comment: что такое контейнер для новичка?

Comment: @Серверныймедведь аналог виртуальной машины, https://medium.com/@quayio/what-is-docker-7f5fd023158f#.2rwz016uz

Comment: один из лучших тюториалов по Docker: https://youtu.be/3c-iBn73dDE

Comment: Спасибо, посмотрю